# Pushing Django updates to production server

Tags: django, database-schema

I need some advice on pushing Django updates, specifically the database updates, from my development server to my production server. I believe that updating the scripts, files, and such will be easy -- simply copy the new files from the dev server to the production server. However, the database updates are what have me unsure.

For Django, I have been using `South` during initial web app creation to change the database schema. If I were to have some downtime on the production server for updates, I could copy all the files over to the production server. These would include and changed `models.py` files which describe the database tables. I could then perform a `python manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto` and then a `python migrate my_app` to update the database based on the new files/`models.py` I've copied over.

Is this an OK solution or are there more appropriate ways to go about updating a database from development to production servers?

Your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `python manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto` will only create the migration based on the changes in `models.py`. To actually apply the migration to the database, you need to run `python manage.py migrate my_app`. Another option would be to create migrations (by running `schemamigration`) on the development server, and then copy over the migration files to the production server and apply migrations by running `migrate`.

Of course, having a source code repository would be way better than copying the files around. You could create migrations on your development server, commit them to the repository, on the production server pull the new files from repository, and finally apply migrations.

Comment: Well, right I left out the second part of the migration operation. I edited my question to reflect that second command. What I'm trying to get at is whether this method is appropriate for pushing database changes to the production server or if I should be looking into a different, more industry standard method of updating a database's schema.